# A Groovy Web Console in a Java webapp?

Tags: java, groovy, console, web-applications

I've been looking at Groovy a little lately, and I love the idea of the [Groovy Web Console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/).

I'm idly wondering whether there's a way to embed a simple web control to write and run scripts from in a web app I might put together myself.

- Is there a plugin-style solution to embed a control like this?
- Are there any resources or guidance out there to help in persisting source code?

Answer (score 2):

The Grails web framework has the Grails console which is basically a Groovy console that has access to your web app's state. More specifically, in the Grails console there are a bunch of predefined variables which you can use to access/change the web app at runtime. For example `ctx` is a predefined variable that provides access to the application's Spring beans (AKA ApplicationContext).

Normally the grails console runs as a desktop app, but there's a [plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/console) available that will let you include it as part of the application itself, and therefore use it via a web browser.

Comment: That does sound like the obvious way to do it.  Does the plugin run the console in any sort of sandbox?  Otherwise, it could be a security nightmare.

Comment: no sandbox, but it's up to the application developers to either disable it on production, or put it behind a layer of security.  For example, if you have an apache -> tomcat configuration, you could protect it on the apache side.