# Upload only source code on Tomcat remote deploy

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, deployment

I'm developing a Java application on tomcat with Eclipse. The problem is that when I have to deploy it on my remote server I have to upload the .war file, that contains also all the libraries, so the upload is slow even if is changed only a little portion of my code. Is there is a way to upload and deploy only the source code of an application?

Comment: The question isn't the same, but the answer might work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257647/simple-way-to-create-patch-on-deployed-grails-application

Answer (score 1):

Well, depends on how large your deployed solution is and how important is it to minimize downtime. Basically it looks like:

1. Build your binaries
2. Stop the web application
3. Copy the files (default folder for deployed tomcat web apps is in /WEB-INF)
4. Start the web application

You can skip 2 and 4, but if you have big web application it can cause recycles that throw the memory use up the roof and web app becomes unusable - you do not want that. I use something little more complex, because i can not afford long downtime.

1. Build your binaries
2. Stop the staging web application
3. Copy the staging files
4. Start the staging web application
5. Swap web bindings so staging becomes new live web application
6. Stop the new staging web application
7. Copy the staging files
8. Start the web application

Web app and staging app share database and content folder.

In any case you can do this manually or automatically. Personally i prefer to do things automatically, but that is just preference. Besides, things can and eventually fail so having a working backup of live environment that you can swap to is very useful.

If you use ANT you can use the [sshexec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html).

Comment: Thanks Margus, but I don't understand... How can I automatically copy only the compiled files on my remote server?

Comment: You copy them over ssh (or insecure ftp). ANT(http://ant.apache.org/) has execute ssh task called **sshexec** that you can use. In order to automate this you do need to write ANT buildfile.