# how to include a groovy console in a JavaEE web app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, groovy, console

what is the best way to include a groovy console in a web app, where I can type in code and see the output? It would be very handy for inspecting/debugging a life app during testing phase.

I found [these tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jeeutils/) but I don't see them in a maven repo. So I thought there might be something else. I'm also seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2008233/520567). It points at [grails console plug-in](http://www.grails.org/plugin/console). But it seems to me to require a grails project what I don't want. I want only a console that I can activate with a maven profile. I'm hoping there are other options now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at the [`GroovyShell`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html). It comes directly with the Groovy download package (groovy-2.1.2.jar). You can pass there a groovy script and provide some data binding.

For example:

```
final String script = "1+x";
try
{
  final Map<String, Object> ctx = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  ctx.put("x", 5);
  final Binding binding = new Binding(ctx);
  final Object result = new GroovyShell(binding).evaluate(script);
  System.out.println(result);
}
catch (final GroovyRuntimeException e)
{
  // something bad happend - e.g. script error
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The stuff around to include that into your webapp should be straight forward.

Comment: +1 and you can find the UI for the grails plugin in [the](https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-console/blob/master/grails-app/taglib/org/grails/plugins/console/ConsoleTagLib.groovy) [source](https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-console/blob/master/grails-app/views/console/index.gsp) [code](https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-console/tree/master/web-app/js) repo

Comment: thanks, this looks straightforward, although I hoped to just add a dependency and have the page ready. But this way I can add a few bindings that would have not been available otherwise.